# Reusable Text Blocks Plugin seems to conflict with Crayon Code Plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

When I am trying to use your plugin's shortcode in a post that uses the Crayon Code Plugin, actually anything with

It messes up the display and I see something like:

```
[crayon-53a2de9537e3a756702714/]
```

instead of

```
....................
<div class="ep_desc">
    ${fn:substring(episode.description,0,300)}
</div>
<div class="ep_desc_bigger">
    ${fn:substring(episode.description,0,600)}
</div>
....................
```

Which behind the scenes is the preformatted text...
I really like your plugin and would want ot use it...

Any suggestions?

Thanks

https://wordpress.org/plugins/reusable-text-blocks/

Answer (score 0):

This issue looks similar to another one: [Crayon Highlighter error when i got the post on my webpage(Wordpress)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27000217/crayon-highlighter-error-when-i-got-the-post-on-my-webpagewordpress)

Without copying the whole answer, in summary, try loading the newest version of the Crayon Syntax Highlighter plugin, then manually change some plugin defaults:

> untick " Attempt to load Crayon's CSS and JavaScript only when needed."
>
> tick "Disable enqueuing for page templates that may contain The Loop."
>
> untick "Load Crayons only from the main WordPress query"

It would also be a good idea to do the same for Reusable Text Blocks plugin (I don't know anything about that one, though).

If the issue persists, where you're not creating the shortcode yourself, you may want to report this issue to the plugin developers (Reusable Text Blocks and Crayon Syntax Highlighter).