# Crayon Highlighter error when i got the post on my webpage(Wordpress)

Tags: php, plugins, wordpress

I build a wordpress plugin but I have a problem.

When I used both wordpress plugin (Mine & Crayon), my code override crayon´s code and encode  it post.
This is the message i watch  [crayon-546b7a833e38a220649795/] instead of the main post.
I´m looking forward to hearing from you.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is an unspecified reported issue on the wordpress support site for the crayon plugin: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-crayon-syntax-highlighter-not-working-in-category-view

Basically, try loading the newest version of the plugin, then manually change some plugin defaults:

> untick " Attempt to load Crayon's CSS and JavaScript only when needed."
>
> tick "Disable enqueuing for page templates that may contain The Loop."
>
> untick "Load Crayons only from the main WordPress query"

This may not be your issue, but at the very least it will provide a better place for you to troubleshoot further.

Once that's done, if you're still encountering issues, you can try this article, which outlines the steps to avoid plugin conflicts when creating your own custom shortcodes. http://www.wpexplorer.com/avoid-theme-plugin-conflicts/